# How to include check

Tags: jquery

I have a function that checks for a particular event and when it detects it is displays an overlay message. Until that happens I need to have **beforeunload** in place to warn a user about potential data loss in case a they decide to leave the page before the task is complete. I added it in the following manner, but even when the task is complete and the beforeunload should not fire it still gets triggered. I think it is due to the **bind**. Is there another way it can be implemented to achieve what i am trying to accomplish?

```
if (!$("#area").find('.item').length) { 
    $("#message").dialog({
        modal: true
    });
 } else {
    $(window).bind("beforeunload", function() {
        return "Are you really sure?";
    });
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `unbind("beforeunload")` to remove your handler.